# How to exclude wrong data input

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

This is a beginner's question.
I want to modify program computing the area of a polygon.
The polygon must have at least 3 sides.
How to exclude wrong data input? (1 side, 0 side, -4 side etc.)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Polygon {

        private static Scanner input;

        public static double polygonArea(double n, double s) {
            // (n*s^2)/(4*tan(π/n))

            return (n * s * s) / (4 * Math.tan(Math.PI / n));

        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Input the number of sides: ");

            double sideNumber = input.nextDouble();

            // System.out.println("Wrong number of sides!");

            System.out.println("Input the length of one of the sides: ");
            double sideLenght = input.nextDouble();

            input.close();

            System.out.println("The area of a polygon is: " + polygonArea(sideNumber, sideLenght));

        }

    }
```

Comment: verify the data -> if invalid read again. Implement this in a loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the input code in a do-while and loop until the the input is valid.

something like

```
input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Input the number of sides: ");
boolean invalidInput = true;
do {
    double sideNumber = input.nextDouble();
    if(sideNumber > 2){
       invalidInput = false;
    }else{
    System.out.println("Wrong number of sides!");
    }
}while (invalidInput)
```

Obviously you can do the same for the other input and check if the value is positive.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class Polygon {

    private static Scanner input;

    public static double polygonArea(double n, double s) {
        // (n*s^2)/(4*tan(π/n))

        return (n * s * s) / (4 * Math.tan(Math.PI / n));

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        input = new Scanner(System.in);
        double sideNumber = 0;

        while (sideNumber <= 2) {
            System.out.println("Input the number of sides: ");
            sideNumber = input.nextDouble();
        };


        // System.out.println("Wrong number of sides!");

        System.out.println("Input the length of one of the sides: ");
        double sideLenght = input.nextDouble();

        input.close();

        System.out.println("The area of a polygon is: " + polygonArea(sideNumber, sideLenght));

    }
}
```

Still missing a different message when the number is wrong.
Have fun learning :)

Answer (score 0):

I finally did it with boolean and do while loop. Thx for help.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double sideNumber;
    input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Input the number of sides: ");
    boolean invalidInput = true;
    do {
        sideNumber = input.nextDouble();
        if (sideNumber > 2) {
            invalidInput = false;
        } else
            System.out.println("Wrong number of sides!");
    } while (invalidInput);


    System.out.println("Input the length of one of the sides: ");
    double sideLenght = input.nextDouble();

    input.close();

    System.out.println("The area of a polygon is: " + polygonArea(sideNumber, sideLenght));
```